# Auto replace --> with arrow

Tags: arrows, editors, auto-completion

I'm currently shifting from MS Word to Latex. Word has the function, which automatically replaces --> with →.

Now in Latex it could replace --> with `$\to$`. But how can this be done? Or is there even a more elegant solution?

Comment: Do you mean as you are typing LaTeX source documents, or is this about converting Word documents?  Many editors can do this sort of substitution. Which editor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I recommend this, but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\check@arrow}{%
  \@ifnextchar-{\check@@arrow}{\std@minus}%
}
\newcommand{\check@@arrow}[1]{% #1 is -
  \@ifnextchar>{\rightarrow\@gobble}{\std@minus\std@minus}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`-
\lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}{\check@arrow}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`-="8000 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a-b$ and $a-->b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works pretty well. But it would be nice to be able to just write `-->` and not always `$-->$`. How is that possible?
And you also mentioned that you wouldn't recommend that solution - what is disadvantage of it?

Comment: @JoLau No, if you want it in text mode you're going to have a wealth of problems. For an arrow in text mode use `\textrightarrow{}` after loading `textcomp`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your text editor. Try to find menu called 'find & replace' or 'replace' it should be quite similar to MS Word.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!!  Answers should be specific solutions to the question posed, rather than general computing advice.

Comment: @Idanko I think the question is about something else. The arrow should automatically be replaced while typing or typesetting the document - without manually going to the menu and call some commands.